# Can't decrease or increase property value of -webkit-transform

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Given this code:

```
$('#slider').css('-webkit-transform', 'translate(-=950px)');
```

It won't do anything. If I manually set the value of `translate` to for example `-1000px`, executing the above code just removes the property completely, as if there was an error parsing it.

Is incrementing or decrementing property value actually possible with CSS transforms?

Comment: Well in these three above nobody mentions the `-=` jQuery "helper" in the question so... doesn't really answers my question

Comment: First line in the first linked duplicate: "As far as I know, basic animates can't animate non-numeric CSS properties."

Comment: Doesn't matter if you're using `-=` or not, you can't `.animate()` the `transform` property, not without some hack (e.g. `step` function).

Comment: I'm not using .animate(). I'm changing the css value directly and a -webkit-transition is taking care of the animation.

Comment: Oh okay then, guess it is not a duplicate. Though relative incrementors won't work with non-numeric/non-px units afaik. You could always retrieve the current value, parse it and increment -- it is more ugly, but works.

Comment: Yeah that's what I was gonna do, but there's two problems to that approach : do I have to retrieve the value of `transform`, `-moz-transform`, `-webkit-transform`, `-o-transform` or `-ms-transform`? Ends up in an ugly mess. And secondly, the value of a transform CSS property in jQuery returns a `matrix(n, n, n, n, n, n)`. Not what I was expecting. 

Easier to calculate it before actually touching the CSS at all!

Comment: Well, jQuery 1.8+ should automatically detect the vendor prefix when you pass the non-prefixed version. I'll do some testing to look for an answer.

Comment: Oh I didn't realize the computed value of the `transform` was a matrix, +1 learned something new today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery's `+=` and `-=` CSS relative numeric values are only valid at [the beginning of the value](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/5a8f76933288396b915800a18240aa17d3414201/src/css.js#L28).

jQuery 1.8+ auto-detects vendor prefixes when the non-prefixed property is not available, so you don't need CSS vendor prefixes in the jQuery code¹.

Seems like CSSOM `getComputedStyle` API (used internally by jQuery's `.css()` getter) always returns a `matrix` for the `transform` property, so let's make use of it:

```
var $el = $('#slider');

var matrix = $.map(
    $el.css('transform') //get computed transform value, e.g.: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 1000, 0)
        .slice(7, -1)    //strip leading "matrix(" and trailing ")"
        .split(', '),    //split values into an array
    Number //map to numbers
);

//[4] is the translateX
matrix[4] -= 950;

$el.css('transform', 'matrix(' + matrix.join(', ') + ')');
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/aGzqs/3/) - Tested in Chrome 33, Firefox 28, IE 10

Note: `.css('transform')` will return `undefined` in browsers which don't support CSS3, you may wrap this code in a feature test to don't throw an error when older browsers are concerned.

Reference - [W3C Recommendation - Coordinate Systems, Transformations and Units](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#TransformMatrixDefined):

> - Translation is equivalent to the matrix
>
>   [image: Translation matrix]
>
>   Or **[1 0 0 1 tx ty]**, where *tx* and *ty* are the distances to translate coordinates in *X* and *Y*, respectively.

---

Luckily `translate` is easy enough to manipulate. Other `transform`s such as `rotate` require some maths -- see [CSS Tricks - Get Value of CSS Rotation through JavaScript](http://css-tricks.com/get-value-of-css-rotation-through-javascript/).

---

¹ Save for a very few exceptions, the `filter` property is [bugged in Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=244295) and fails jQuery's auto-detection.

Comment: Thanks for this comprehensive answer! Very clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

[No, it's not possible.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-transforms-1/#two-d-transform-functions)

Don't confuse CSS with jQuery helpers.

Comment: I know it's not possible in CSS, but jQuery does it perfectly with margin-left, for instance... I was just wondering if it did the same for more complex CSS values than mere pixel values

Comment: My mistake, I didn't even know jQuery could do that outside `animate`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `webkitTransform` in your JS instead of `-webkit-transform`.

Also, you can't add or subtract from the current value of `translate`, since you can't get the value of `translate` with JS/jQuery. Either add a class in CSS and use `addClass`/`.removeClass`, or set a single number of `px`.

Comment: Thank you, I'll just supply a static number to translate. Out of curiosity, what's the advantage of `webkitTransform` vs `-webkit-transform` in my Javascript?

Comment: `webkitTransform` is the JS name for `-webkit-transform`. Similar rules apply to all CSS properties with a `-` in them. e.g., `border-radius` becomes `borderRadius`.